# Compile failed in java NetBeans

Tags: java

> hi i have done all my coding in java but i got into a error with this line and i have trying many some ways to fix it wont work can someone help me please!

on line 284

C:\Users-----\Magazine\src\magazine\Client.java:284: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Supplement
                                                        payCustomer.get(index).setSupp((payCustomer.get(index).aListSize()-1)).setSup(supList.get(i));
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
C:\Users-----\Magazine\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users-----\Magazine\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

```js
// CLIENT CLASS
package magazine;

import java.util.*;

public class Client {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SCAN THE TEXT INPUT FORM THE SOURCE
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String customerList = "";
        String menuList = "";
        String supplementList = "";
        double cost;
        // CREATE A LIST OF USING FRIST NAME, LASIT NAME, EMAIL, PAYMENT METHOD
        String firstn = "";
        String lastn = "";
        String email = "";
        String pMethod = "";
        String pFN = "";
        String pLN = "";
        // BOOLWAN TO ALTER CUSTOMER CLASS
        boolean checkCustomer;
        boolean checkDeleteCustomer;
        //REMOVE THE ELEMENT BY 1
        int index = -1; 

        Magazine newMag = new Magazine("", 19.00);
        // ADDITION ELEMENTS IN ARRAYLIST
        ArrayList<Supplement> supList = new ArrayList<>();
        //CONSTRUCT MAGAZINE
        supList.add(new Supplement("categorie", 5.99));
        supList.add(new Supplement("categorie", 8.99));
        supList.add(new Supplement("categorie", 3.55));
        supList.add(new Supplement("categorie", 9.50));

        ArrayList<payment> payCustomer = new ArrayList<>();

        //A NEW PAYMENT FOR CUSTOMER 
        payCustomer.add(new payment(""));
        //GET SUPPLEMENT 
        payCustomer.get(0).setSupp(supList.get(1));
        payCustomer.get(0).setSupp(supList.get(2));
        //ADDING A NEW SUPPLEMENT
        payCustomer.add(new payment(""));
        payCustomer.get(1).setSupp(supList.get(0));
        payCustomer.get(1).setSupp(supList.get(3));
        //ADD ANEW PAYMENT
        payCustomer.add(new payment(""));
        //ADD A NEW ASSOCIATED FOR THE CUSTOMER
        payCustomer.get(0).addAssC(new AssociateCustomer(""));
        //ADD A SUPPLEMENT FOR ASSOCIATED CUSTOMER
        payCustomer.get(0).getAssC(0).setSupp(supList.get(2));
        payCustomer.get(1).addAssC(new AssociateCustomer(""));
        payCustomer.get(1).getAssC(0).setSupp(supList.get(2));
        payCustomer.get(2).addAssC(new AssociateCustomer("));
        
        //WHILE LOOP TO EXIT THE MENU BY E
        while (!menuList.equals("E")) {
            //DISPLAY MENU BY OPTIONS
         i rook this part off for my own reson do not want any one copy my work!!
          

            menuList = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            if (!menuList.equals("E")) {
                switch (menuList) {
                    case "1":
                        System.out.println("Printing out the text of all the emails for all customemr");

                        for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                            for (int w = 0; w < 4; w++) {
                                System.out.println("Week " + (w + 1));
                                System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName());
                                System.out.println(newMag.getName() + " for Week" + (w + 1));

                                //LOOK FOR A SUPPLEMNT WITH LOOP 
                                if (payCustomer.get(i).suppSize() > 0) {
                                    System.out.println("A list for your supplement:");
                                    for (int s = 0; s < payCustomer.get(i).suppSize(); s++) {
                                        System.out.println((s + 1) + "| " + payCustomer.get(i).getSupp(s).getSuppName());
                                    }
                                    System.out.println();
                                }
                                if (payCustomer.get(i).aListSize() > 0) {
                                    for (int c = 0; c < payCustomer.get(i).aListSize(); c++) {
                                        System.out.println("Week " + (w + 1));
                                        System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName());
                                        System.out.println(newMag.getName() + " for Week" + (+1));
                                        if (payCustomer.get(i).suppSize() > 0) {
                                            System.out.println("A list for your supplement:");
                                            for (int s = 0; s < payCustomer.get(i).suppSize(); s++) {
                                                System.out.println((s + 1) + "| " + payCustomer.get(i).getSupp(s).getSuppName());
                                            }
                                            System.out.println();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                           break;
                            
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("Printing out payment for emails");
                        for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                            cost = 0;
                            cost += newMag.getCost();

                            for (int a = 0; a < payCustomer.get(i).suppSize(); a++) {
                                cost += payCustomer.get(i).getSupp(a).getCost();
                            }
                            for (int b = 0; b < payCustomer.get(i).aListSize(); b++) {
                                cost += newMag.getCost();
                                for (int a = 0; a < payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(b).suppSize() ;a++) {
                                    cost += payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(b).getSupp(a).getCost();
                                }
                            }
                            cost *= 4; //multiple by 4 weeks

                            System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName());
                            System.out.println("Amount Due:" + cost);

                        }
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("Creating a new (Customer) or (Associated Customer)");
                        System.out.println("Please select one of the options below");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("[1]--> Customer");
                        System.out.println("[2]--> Associate Customer");
                        customerList = sc.nextLine();

                        switch (customerList) {
                            case "1":
                                System.out.println("Input new customer");

                                firstn = "";
                                lastn = "";
                                email = "";
                                pMethod = "";
                                checkCustomer = true;

                                System.out.println("Please Enter First Name:");
                                firstn = sc.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Please Enter Last Namer:");
                                lastn = sc.nextLine();

                                for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                                    if ((payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName().equals(firstn)) && (payCustomer.get(i).getLastName().equals(lastn))) {
                                        System.out.println("Customer exists, Please try again.");
                                        checkCustomer = false;
                                    }
                                    for (int j = 0; j < payCustomer.get(i).aListSize(); j++) {
                                        if ((payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(j).getFirstName().equals(firstn) && (payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(j).getLastName().equals(lastn)))) {
                                            System.out.println("Customer exists, Please try again.");
                                            checkCustomer = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (checkCustomer == true) {
                                    System.out.println("Please Enter Email");
                                    email = sc.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println("Please Select Payment Method");
                                    System.out.println("[1]--> Credit Card");
                                    System.out.println("[2]--> Direct Debit");

                                    while ((!pMethod.equals("Credit Card")) && (!pMethod.equals("Direct Debit"))) {
                                        pMethod = sc.nextLine();
                                        //SWITCH METHOD FOR PAUMENT AS CREDIT AND DIRECT DEBIT
                                        switch (pMethod) {
                                            case "1":
                                                pMethod = "Credit Card";
                                                break;
                                            case "2":
                                                pMethod = "Direct Debit";
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    payCustomer.add(new payment(firstn, lastn, email, pMethod));
                                    
                                    System.out.println("Adding Supplement to Customer");
                                    System.out.println("Please Enter 'Y/YES' to accept or 'N/NO' to reject: ");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < supList.size(); i++) {
                                        supplementList = "";
                                        System.out.println("Title: " + supList.get(i).getSuppName() + "Cost: $" + supList.get(i).getCost() + "(Y/N)");
                                        while ((!supplementList.equals(("Y")) && (!supplementList.equals("N")))) {
                                            supplementList = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                                            switch (supplementList) {
                                                case "Y":
                                                    payCustomer.get(payCustomer.size() - 1).setSupp(supList.get(i));
                                                    break;
                                                case "N":
                                                    break;
                                                default:
                                                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                                                    break;

                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            
                            //CREATING A NEW ASSOCIATION FOR THE CUSTUOMER BY FRIST AND KAST NAME AND EMAIL
                            case "2":
                                System.out.println("++ Creating new Associate Customer ++");
                                System.out.println();
                                pFN = "";
                                pLN = "";
                                firstn = "";
                                lastn = "";
                                email = "";
                                checkCustomer = false;
                                index = -1;
                                //DISPLAY THE INFROMATION FOR THE CUSTOMER
                                System.out.println("Information about the Customer");
                                System.out.println("Please Enter the First Name:");
                                pFN = sc.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Please Enter the Last Name:");
                                pLN = sc.nextLine();

                                for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                                    if ((payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName().equals(pFN)) && (payCustomer.get(i).getLastName().equals(pLN))) {
                                        System.out.println("Customer exists");
                                        //A STEMENT "TRUE" IF THE CUSTOMER BEEN CREATED 
                                        checkCustomer = true; 
                                        index = i;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (checkCustomer == true) {
                                    System.out.println("Please Enter First Name:");
                                    firstn = sc.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name:");
                                    lastn = sc.nextLine();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                                        if ((payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName().equals(firstn)) && (payCustomer.get(i).equals(lastn))) {
                                            System.out.println("Customer Exists");
                                            checkCustomer = false;
                                        }
                                        for (int c = 0; c < payCustomer.get(i).aListSize(); c++) {
                                            if ((payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getFirstName().equals(firstn)) && (payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getLastName().equals(lastn))) {
                                                System.out.println("Customer Exists");
                                                checkCustomer = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (checkCustomer == true) {
                                        System.out.println("Enter Email");
                                        email = sc.nextLine();
                                        payCustomer.get(index).addAssC(new AssociateCustomer(firstn, lastn, email));
                                        for (int i = 0; i < supList.size(); i++) {
                                            supplementList = "";
                                            System.out.println("Title: " + supList.get(i).getSuppName() + "Cost: $" + supList.get(i).getCost() + "(Y/N)");
                                            while ((!supplementList.equals(("Y")) && (!supplementList.equals("N")))) {
                                                supplementList = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                                                switch (supplementList) {
                                                    case "Y":
   The problem is here   --->                 payCustomer.get(index).setSupp((payCustomer.get(index).aListSize()-1)).setSup(supList.get(i));
                                                        break;
                                                    case "N":
                                                        break;
                                                    default:
                                                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                                                        break;

                                                }
                                            }

                                        }

                                    }
                                } 
                                else {
                                    // LOOK UP FOR CUSTOMER NAME 
                                    System.out.println("Customer doesn't exist");
                                }
                                break;
                                 default:
                                System.out.println(" Invalid Input");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                            // TO DELATE A CUSTOMER
                            case "4":
                                System.out.println("Delete Customer");
                                firstn = "";
                                lastn = "";
                                checkDeleteCustomer = false;
                                //ENTER THE INFO AS FRIST AND LAIST NAME TO DELETE 
                                System.out.println("Please Enter First Name");
                                firstn = sc.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name");
                                lastn = sc.nextLine();

                                for (int i = 0; i < payCustomer.size(); i++) {
                                    if ((payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName().equals(firstn)) && (payCustomer.get(i).getLastName().equals(lastn))) {
                                        checkDeleteCustomer = true;
                                        // DISPLAY MESSAGE IF THE CUSTOMER BEEN DELETED 
                                        System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName() + "," + payCustomer.get(i).getLastName() + "been deleted");
                                        payCustomer.remove(i);
                                    }

                                    for (int c = 0; c < payCustomer.get(i).aListSize(); c++) {
                                        if ((payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getFirstName().equals(firstn)) && (payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getLastName().equals(lastn))) {
                                            checkDeleteCustomer = true;
                                            System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getFirstName() + payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getLastName() + "been deleted");
                                            payCustomer.get(i).removeAC(c);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (checkDeleteCustomer == false) {
                                    System.out.println("Customer doesn't exist");

                                }
                                break;
                            // LOOK UP FOR A CUSTOMER BY NAME 
                            case "5":
                                System.out.println("Display customer's name: ");
                                for (int i = 0;i<payCustomer.size();i++){
                                    System.out.println("Customer #" + (i+1)+ " = " +payCustomer.get(i).getFirstName()+ " " + payCustomer.get(i).getLastName());
                                    if(payCustomer.get(i).aListSize()>0){
                                        System.out.println("Associate Customers are: ");
                                        for(int c = 0;c< payCustomer.get(i).aListSize();c++){
          
                                            System.out.println(payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getFirstName()+payCustomer.get(i).getAssC(c).getLastName());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                                
                            default:
                                //DISPLAY MESSAGES IF THE INPUT INVALID
                                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                                break;
                        }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the error?

Comment: i just want to understand why this error comes up when i billed the project and when i  Add a new customer as Associate Customer the program wont go in after this! the error will come again! that will nice if you can explain to me what i did wrong

Comment: You are passing an integer to a method which expects a `Supplement`.

Comment: yes as will show the cost and name first and list with email to the user!

Comment: would you mind if you can show a way to do passing an integer to a method please!

Comment: Anyone can help please with passing as i got error i get this when i add a new customer as Association and add a new categories i receive this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: magazine.payment.setSupp.setSup
 at magazine.Client.main